# inserting values in SQL columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table t1 having two columns (col_1,col_2)

i  want to insert data in these column by passing a string as paramater by store procedure

but the problem is that when i call the procedure

```
call insert_csv('amjad,ali');
```

it show:   MySQL said:

> #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
     DELIMITER //

  CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_csv`(_list MEDIUMTEXT)

     BEGIN


    DECLARE _next TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE _nextlen INT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE _value TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    iterator:
    LOOP

      IF LENGTH(TRIM(_list)) = 0 OR _list IS NULL THEN
        LEAVE iterator;
      END IF;

      SET _next = SUBSTRING_INDEX(_list,',',1);


      SET _nextlen = LENGTH(_next);

      SET _value = TRIM(_next);

      INSERT INTO tblloaninfo (col_1,col_2) VALUES (_value);
      SET _list = INSERT(_list,1,_nextlen + 1,'');
    END LOOP;

    END //

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your question title should describe your problem.

Comment: The error is here `INSERT INTO tblloaninfo (col_1,col_2) VALUES (_value);` You provide only one value for to columns. The right query must be: `INSERT INTO tblloaninfo (col_1,col_2) VALUES (_value1, _value2);`

Comment: *when i call the procedure `call insert_csv('amjad,ali');`* Show the final state of a table which you want to achieve after this query.

Comment: This code `SET _list = INSERT(_list,1,_nextlen + 1,'');` also not valid. What this query should to do?

Comment: What's expected to happen if you do `call insert_csv('amjad');` or `call insert_csv('amjad,ali,xyz,abc');`?

Comment: @jarlh  it shows me : #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: But what do you _want_ to happen?

Comment: i want to pass 'amjad,ali' in seperate column                                                                  i.e amjad in col_1 and ali in col_2

Answer (score 1):

here:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblloaninfo (col_1,col_2) VALUES (_value);
```

you are asking it to fill two columns, with only a single value. It isn't clear what the two values *should be* here, but: the number of values on the right (1 in this case) should match the number of columns (2 in this case) on the left.

If `_value` is a string that happens to contain a comma: that isn't how it works. It won't be split into two values - it'll still just be one value: *a string that contains a comma*.

Comment: but how to split that comma so that i could put in seperate column

Comment: @tajamulhussain by passing in two different inputs (parameters, etc); C# is a much better place to do any splitting than SQL

Comment: but i want to do it in mysql

Comment: @tajamulhussain then you'll need to get familiar with `INSTR` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (and associated methods): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_csv`(_list MEDIUMTEXT)
BEGIN
iterator: 
LOOP
    IF LOCATE(',', _list) THEN
        SET @element := SUBSTRING_INDEX(_list, ',', 2);
        SET _list := TRIM(SUBSTRING(_list FROM 2 + LENGTH(@element)));
        INSERT INTO tblloaninfo (col_1, col_2) 
            SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@element, ',',  1)), 
                   TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@element, ',', -1));
    ELSE 
        LEAVE iterator;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7a7fe99d36d08f07a5b9a1aa2389e0e)

Comment: thanks a lot. I want to ask one more thing..... if i pass columns name as string how can pass that? i mean i have to copy columns from another table

Comment: @tajamulhussain Investigate dynamic SQL (PREPARE statement).

Comment: but i want to do it by passing columns name as string so i do not need prepare statement

Comment: Try... when it doesn't work, go back to prepared statements.